# Bibliography @InCollection: Emphasize Collection Title and omit 'in'

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am fairly new to LateX and I would like to modify the way that chapters in collections are displayed in the bibliography. I use JabRef, TexStudio Bibtex, and the natbib package. I use the agsm stlye for my harvard-stlye bibliography.

I cannot get my bibliography entries for chapters in collections to look like they are supposed to. The chapter title should be followed by a full stop and the editor's name. It should say (ed.) after the editor. The collection title has to be emphasised. The location and publisher have to be switched and columns substituted for commas.

How can this be achived?

What it should look like: 
[image: What it should look like]

What it currently looks like: 
[image: What it currently looks like]

The code for  `@InCollection` currently looks like this:

`FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title "title" output.check }
  if$
  author "author" item.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.edition output
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.chapter.pages output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}`

Any help is greatly appreciated!